# Get the Sum of counts populated with count if queries on other columns - to the last column onto the right

Tags: mysql

I get this result with the below query

[image]

```
            SELECT
                owner.country AS country,COUNT(main.accounts) as "total_accounts",COUNT(IF(main.status = "active_accounts",1,NULL)) as "status",COUNT(IF(main.total_toys = 10,1,NULL)) as "10ToyOwners"
            FROM accounts AS main
            JOIN (
                SELECT MAX(hist.dyna_id) AS maxid,
                    hist.LastEditor AS lasteditor
                FROM history_gt AS hist
                    WHERE 
                        hist.LastEditor != "abc@example.com"
                    GROUP BY 
                        hist.dyna_id
                )AS history 
                    ON 
                        main.id = history.maxid
            LEFT JOIN
                all_users AS owner
            ON
                history.lasteditor = owner.primary_email 
            GROUP BY 
                country
            ORDER BY 
            main.ticket_number
```

What I looking for is to get the Sum of 'total_accounts - active_accounts + 10ToyOwner' populated on columns 'b,c,d' with count if queries - to the last column onto the right (screenshot below)

[image]

```
                COUNT(IF(main.status = 'active_accounts', 1, NULL)) AS status,
                COUNT(IF(main.total_toys = 10, 1, NULL)) AS tenToyOwners,
```

-- new term below

```
status + tenToyOwner  AS desired_total <-- this line doenst work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you only need to add another term to your current select clause:

```
SELECT
    owner.country AS country,
    COUNT(main.accounts) AS total_accounts,
    COUNT(IF(main.status = 'active_accounts', 1, NULL)) AS status,
    COUNT(IF(main.total_toys = 10, 1, NULL)) AS 10ToyOwners,
    -- new term below
    COUNT(main.accounts) - COUNT(IF(main.status = 'active_accounts', 1, NULL)) +
        COUNT(IF(main.total_toys = 10, 1, NULL)) AS desired_total
FROM accounts AS main
INNER JOIN ( ...
```

I have omitted the rest of your query for brevity.  Note that we can't use the aliases to generate your new term, because an alias can't be used by the same selectnin which it is defined.  We could subquery your current query and use the aliases, but I don't see a need for that.

Comment: that did it . One quick question - i tried adding the aliases instead of repeating the count term but doesn't seem to work, can you suggest

Comment: hi Tim please see my added comment in the query for aliases

Comment: @ManurajSebastian Did you read my answer?  You _can't_ use aliases like that, you would have to subquery.  But, I don't recommend it.